# Loading Excel files with SSIS with different names. Getting error 0x80004005

Tags: foreach, ssis, enumerator

I have an SSIS package that looks through excel files with a date at the end of each file. I have watched many vidoes but can't find an answer. If I move the "original file" that I used with the connection manager(see link for screenshot) the package fails to complete with "Error: The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80004005 "Unspecified error". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate." If I then put the file back to the correct place it works again. My question is do I have to have the file there forever? Is there no way to do this and it not look for that file to exist?

[image: Connection Manager]
[image: Connection Manager]

Comment: Mind tossing a picture of the Control Flow up so I can see how you've structured the package?

Comment: My guess is that you will need to set the DelayValidation property on the Excel Connection Manager, the Data Flow and if it exist, the File System Task that archives the file after importing

Comment: I have put delay validation on all processes. The error is not when I open the package but when I run it. See new Screenshot in OP above. or here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJEfP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using static file names. If you are OK with using static file names, then you will have to have some other process update that file periodically. However, if you want to be more dynamic where the process loops over multiple files, then in the ForEachLoop Enumerator, you just set the following settings:

Note: using `*.xlsx` is the method for getting any file with the extension of `xlsx`.

[image]

You then map the file path to a variable:

[image]

You then set your Connection Manager's ConnectionString property to the file path:

[image]

Comment: [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"] Error: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

Comment: Error: The result of the expression "@[User::SPS_47PlusDirectory]" on property "\Package.Connections[Excel Connection Manager].Properties[ConnectionString]" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the value that it is trying to use? It should be the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN). For example, on a local drive it is `C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.xlsx` whereas on a network drive it would be `\\SomeNetworkFolder\SomeFile.xlsx`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did not do it correctly. After reviewing again what you posted it seems to be working. Thanks!